# Stop linux being detected in TCP/IP stack fingerprint when using a proxy?

Tags: proxy, virtual-machine, tcp, fingerprint, privacy

If I connect to a socks5 on my windows 7 virtual machine and go on www.doileak.com, it tells me that javascript and user agent show Windows OS but the TCP/IP fingerprint shows that it is a linux distribution, hence I am probably using a virtual machine or a proxy. The virtual machine is being run on a Windows host using virtual box. Is this fingerprint because the proxy I am connected to is on a linux distribution? And if so, is there any way to prevent that from happening ?

Answer (score 2):

doileak.com uses `p0f` [to fingerprint](https://www.doileak.com/about.html).

The [source](https://github.com/p0f/p0f/blob/master/p0f.fp), for Windows:

```
; -------
; Windows
; -------

label = s:win:Windows:XP
sig   = *:128:0:*:16384,0:mss,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:65535,0:mss,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:65535,0:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:65535,1:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:65535,2:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0

label = s:win:Windows:7 or 8
sig   = *:128:0:*:8192,0:mss,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:8192,2:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig   = *:128:0:*:8192,8:mss,nop,ws,nop,nop,sok:df,id+:0
sig = *:128:0:*:8192,2:mss,nop,ws,sok,ts:df,id+:0
```

Linux:

```
; -----
; Linux
; -----

; The variation here is due to ws, sok, or ts being adaptively removed if the
; client initiating the connection doesn't support them. Use tools/p0f-sendsyn
; to get a full set of up to 8 signatures.


label = s:unix:Linux:3.x
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,0:mss:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,0:mss,sok,ts:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,0:mss,nop,nop,ts:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,0:mss,nop,nop,sok:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,*:mss,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,*:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,*:mss,nop,nop,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*10,*:mss,nop,nop,sok,nop,ws:df:0

label = s:unix:Linux:2.4-2.6
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,sok,ts:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,nop,nop,ts:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,nop,nop,sok:df:0

label = s:unix:Linux:2.4.x
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,nop,nop,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,0:mss,nop,nop,sok,nop,ws:df:0

label = s:unix:Linux:2.6.x
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,*:mss,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,*:mss,sok,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig   = *:64:0:*:mss*4,*:mss,nop,nop,ts,nop,ws:df:0
sig = *:64:0:*:mss*4,*:mss,nop,nop,sok,nop,ws:df:0
```

Knowing the above fingerprints, you simply convert your Linux VM to look like Windows.

[The fingerprint format](https://github.com/p0f/p0f/blob/master/docs/README#L513-L624):

`sig = ver:ittl:olen:mss:wsize,scale:olayout:quirks:pclass`

You will need to spoof the following to change your fingerprint:

- OS TTL: `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=128` (Windows)
- Maximum Segment Size: `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.route.min_adv_mss=1460`
- TCP window size: `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='8192 87380 4194304' && sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='8192 87380 4194304'`
- Unfortunately, at the `olayout` section you cannot change these settings in Linux. So, you cannot spoof these. The same is true in the `quirks` section. It just so happens that `olayout` "...is one of the most valuable TCP fingerprinting signals."